# Azure websites & MediaWiki: how to enable emails sending

Tags: email, azure, mediawiki, pear, azure-web-app-service

for example, when user creates an account, resets password etc.

First step is to set mail server credentials in LocalSettings.php file, as per this document: [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:$wgSMTP#Example_using_Google_Mail](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3a%24wgSMTP#Example_using_Google_Mail)

But after you do this, you will get "PEAR mail package is not installed" error message. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's relatively simple:

1. Make sure your mail server credentials are correct
2. FTP to root folder and rename index.php into index.php.old - otherwise it gets overridden
3. Install PEAR manager, using "[Hosted website](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php#installation.getting.hosted)" workflow
4. **Rename pear.conf into pear.ini** - otherwise you won't be able to start web manager
5. Create .user.ini file in your root folder and add your physical path to pear into *include_path* variable - kudoz to this article: http://chrisrisner.com/Using-PEAR-with-Windows-Azure-Websites-and-PHP
6. Open web manager (http://domain.name/index.php) and install the following packages in PEAR (not sure if some of them are redundant but after I installed them, i was able to connect to GMAIL server)

   - Auth_SASL
   - Mail
   - Mail_Mime
   - Net_SMTP
7. Rename index.php into index.php.pear, and go-pear.php into go-pear.php.pear, and rename index.php.old back to index.php
8. Try to register - you should get an email

Comment: If the progress of Pear stall at 20% or 40% you will need to update the links inside pear. Once it's done it will install as a charm.

Comment: @Nordes how would I do that - "update links inside pear"?

Comment: It's not you, but when I tried to use the "go-pear" it didn't worked. I had to update the links inside the $bootstrap_files variable.

Comment: updated link - makes installing PEAR much easier: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/04/03/installing-php-package-on-azure-website-using-pear-package-manager.aspx