# How to get pear working on Azure website?

Tags: azure, pear

Related question:
[Azure websites & MediaWiki: how to enable emails sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981481/azure-websites-mediawiki-how-to-enable-emails-sending)

I am trying to send mail with PEAR.
The error message at 
http://modeldoc.azurewebsites.net/wiki/index.php?title=Special:RequestAccount is

Exception from line 268 of D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\includes\mail\UserMailer.php: PEAR mail package is not installed

What I did (on local linux machine)

```
php go-pear.phar.php
```

This created a folder
wiki/pear, with subfolders
wiki/pear/share,
wiki/pear/bin etc.

I added .user.ini in wiki/ with values

```
display_errors = On
upload_max_filesize = 10M
include_path=".;D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\pear\share\pear\PEAR"
```

I pushed the changes i.e.
    git add .
    git commit -m "add pear path"
    git push

but it didn't work.  I also tried different paths in .user.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\PEAR` from the include path.

The include path needs to be the one `System.php` is in - see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php